# Return false if one call returns false in a function

Tags: php, logic

This is a basic logic question: I have a function that should return **true if all methods/queries return true**. However, with this approach here, the whole function can return true when the last foreach call returns true – how do I prevent this?

```
function deleteAllSuccess(){
    $all_query_ok = true;
    $params = array('A', 'B', 'C');

    deleteOne() ? null : $all_query_ok = false;
    deleteTwo() ? null : $all_query_ok = false;

    foreach($params as $p){
        $all_query_ok = deleteThree($p);
        $all_query_ok = deleteFour($p);
    }

   if($all_query_ok){
       commit();
       return true;
   }else{
       rollback();
       return false;
}
```

Comment: The best idea is to fire `return false` when you got the first `false` and don't go to the end of the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be to use the [`&` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) if you want every function to execute (or the [`&&` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for short-circuiting):

```
foreach($params as $p){
    $all_query_ok = $all_query_ok & deleteThree($p);
    $all_query_ok = $all_query_ok & deleteFour($p);
}

return $all_query_ok;
```

Or for brevity, you can use the `&=` compound assignment operator:

```
foreach($params as $p){
    $all_query_ok &= deleteThree($p);
    $all_query_ok &= deleteFour($p);
}
```

But in case you want to exit the function as soon as any of the functions return false, you can do something like this:

```
if (!deleteOne()) return false;
if (!deleteTwo()) return false;

foreach($params as $p){
    if (!deleteThree($p)) return false;
    if (!deleteFour($p)) return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: The first one suits because I need a rollback if it fails, so I can't just return false on first fail.

Comment: @dfdfdf In case you needed every function to run and you just wanted to collect the results, I realized there was a problem with my initial solution. Please see my updated answer for a better solution.